# Restore data from 9.1.7 version postgres file to 8.4 version postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, restore

I want to restore data from postgres file. I have a file, when I open the file in notepad the version of the file is 9.1.7 PostgreSQL and this file contain all tables structure and database but the file doesn't have an extension. I want to restore all table structure and data from the file to my PostgreSQL 8.4 version database, because my project is based on PostgreSQL 8.4 version.

How can I do this?

Comment: What did you try so far? What errors did you get using pg_restore or psql?

Comment: when i try to open file like sql script , it generate an error when inert the data in tables.

Answer (score 2):

Re the type of file: If it starts with "PGDMP" it's a PostgreSQL custom-format dump that must be restored with the `pg_restore` command. Otherwise it's most likely to be a plain SQL dump, and there'll be a comment at the start saying so.

A dump for a newer PostgreSQL will not restore to an older PostgreSQL version. You must either upgrade your project to 9.1 (why are you using such an old version as 8.4 for new work anyway?) or:

- install PostgreSQL 9.1
- Restore the dump to PostgreSQL 9.1
- Use PostgreSQL 8.4's `pg_dump` to dump the 9.1 database
- Restore the result into your 8.4 database

All seem too hard? Then upgrade your project to a recent version. Downgrading PostgreSQL between major versions isn't really supported or recommended.

BTW, always show **exact text** of error messages, and rather than describing what you see in notepad, please *show us some of it too* so we can see exactly what's there, not just your interpretation of what's there.

Comment: now i install postgresSQL 9.1 but when i try to restore the file , it will generate error , that "this is the text file dumb".

Comment: @HarmeetSingh That isn't an error PostgreSQL produces. Please show the *full, exact error message text* along with how you ran the restore. If you're translating from another language, feel free to show the original un-translated error, it's easier for me to reverse-translate than to guess what the error really was.

Comment: The error is this "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin\pg_restore.exe --host localhost --port 5432 --username "postgres" --dbname "old_qrata" --no-password  --list "C:\Users\Nanaksar\Desktop\Qrata PPT\old_qrata_db_bckup"
pg_restore: [archiver] input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql.

Process returned exit code 1." But Manullay i have done to import da data.

Comment: @HarmeetSingh The error tells you what to do. Use `psql`, not `pg_restore` since it's an SQL text format dump. See the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup-dump.html#BACKUP-DUMP-RESTORE